# nodejs react functions are not invoked

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, electron

Not all functions are invoked in NodeJS application, What mistake I am making? Need help.
I have following function in react electron nodejs application

```
function setData({
val1,
val2,
val3
}) {
  methods.set_val1(val1);
  methods.set_val2(val2);
  methods.set_val3(val3);
}

const methods = {
set_val1(data) {
    return setCharData(data);
  },
set_val2(data) {
    return setIntData(data);
  },
set_val3(data) {
    // Set val3
    return setFloatData(data);
  }
}
```

While invoking the function on an event i just see val1 and val3 set, val2 is not set.
If I change the sequence then also the first and last one gets executed. here is the snipped of invoking the function.

```
event.on('preset_data_event', preset_data => {
  console.log("Data to preset", preset_data);
  setData(preset_data);
});
```

> Output is Data to preset {val1:1,val2:2,val3:3}

Comment: What is `preset_data` can you console.log that and include it in the question?

Comment: preset_data is one event and another one is json object to carry all 3 values. preset_data = {val1:22,val2:11,val3:43}

Comment: Thanks. The code you have included doesn't have any errors - could it be that `set_val2` itself has a bug? I recreated the code in a repl here - https://repl.it/@madebydavid/VengefulInconsequentialDesigners you can see that all of the `set_` methods are called

Comment: thanks for code snippet, set_val2() gets invoked if i change the position from middle to first or last, whichever is in mid, doesn't run.. Strange

Comment: very strange maybe the other `set_val` functions have some side effects?